# IntelliJ Packages ending the same way scope

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a project with a huge codebase and, I'm trying to create a scope in the IntelliJ hierarchy as to filter on the methods which are calling a certain method.

I have taken a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope-language-syntax-reference.html, and, it shows an example of:

- com.intellij.openapi..*

This would show all classes inside such package and sub packages. What I'm trying to do is something like:

- com..*openapi
- com..*.openapi

As to search for classes with a package name ending in .openapi, maybe one of them is com.intellij.openapi, and other is com.eclipse.openapi, I would like to write an expression for such scope, but I can't figure out how what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you selected the package

- com..*openapi

You still need to add a wildcard to the ending of your package to match on files, like this:

- com..*openapi..*

That will give you the results like

- com.intellij.openapi.Foo
- com.eclipse.openapi.Bar

And also

- com.intellij.openapi.someotherpackage.Foo

If you want only the 'ending' package, you should use:

- com..*openapi.*

That will only match:

- com.intellij.openapi.Foo
- com.eclipse.openapi.Bar

But not

- com.intellij.openapi.someotherpackage.Foo

Comment: Now it manages to find the files, although when I use the hierarchy directly, I can't see any classes at all (and there are a few in the tree). Still, in the Scopes menu it finds the amount of files in the project. If I change the scope to 'All' I can nagivate via the tree and I'll end up in those files, which, in the Scope menu, are marked in green, why?